# Unhashable type when subclassing `int`

Tags: python

Let us define a very simple `Test` class, which inherits from `int`:

```
TEST_DICT = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}


class Test(int):

    def __str__(self):
        return TEST_DICT[self]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Test(1))
```

This will print `a`, which is the representation of `1` for this `Test` class, as expected.

Now, let us redefine the `__eq__` method:

```
TEST_DICT = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}


class Test(int):

    def __str__(self):
        return TEST_DICT[self]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self == other
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return str(self) == other
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Test(1))
```

This, however, results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(Test(1))
  File "test.py", line 4, in __str__
    return TEST_DICT[self]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Test'
```

Could somebody explain why is this happening and how could I avoid this error, while still being able to redefine the `__eq__` method?

Comment: `return self == other` will result in infinite recursion.

Comment: @interjay: yes, I see that in Python 2, I wonder why Python 3 gives me that traceback though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html:

> here are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of x==y does not imply that x!=y is false. Accordingly, when defining **eq**(), one should also define **ne**() so that the operators will behave as expected. See the paragraph on **hash**() for some important notes on creating hashable objects which support custom comparison operations and are usable as dictionary keys.

And

> If a class does not define a **cmp**() or **eq**() method it should not define a **hash**() operation either; **if it defines __cmp__() or __eq__() but not __hash__(), its instances will not be usable in hashed collections.** If a class defines mutable objects and implements a **cmp**() or **eq**() method, it should not implement **hash**(), since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).
>
> User-defined classes have **cmp**() and **hash**() methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and x.**hash**() returns a result derived from id(x).

Comment: Seems like the 2nd quote says that fairly explicitly?

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer with an example implementation, just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DeepSpace for the link to the documentation on the data model.

A possible implementation, for reference:

```
TEST_DICT = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}


class Test(int):

    def __str__(self):
        return TEST_DICT[int(self)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return int(self) == other
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return str(self) == other
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(int(self))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Test(1))
```

Note the conversions `int(self)` in `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` to avoid infinite recursion.